# Understanding AppDomains and strong naming

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm trying to create a sandbox for where I can load plugins. I create the `AppDomain` and specify a `StrongName` for my host assembly, and my understanding is that any code running in the assembly that is strongly named runs in Full Trust. However this seems not the case.

Example,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
    var setup = new AppDomainSetup()
        {
            ApplicationBase = "C:\\Temporary\\Sandbox"
        };

    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox",
                                        null,
                                        setup,
                                        permissions,
                                        typeof (PluginHost).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>());

    var handle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(domain,
                                                typeof (PluginHost).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName,
                                                typeof (PluginHost).FullName);

    var host = (PluginHost) handle.Unwrap();
    host.RunPlugin();
}
```

PluginHost (defined in the same assembly I'm strong naming),

```
public class PluginHost : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void RunPlugin()
    {
        File.ReadAllText("C:\\Passwords.txt");

        var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Plugins\UnsafePlugin.dll");
        var t = asm.GetType("UnsafePlugin.FooPlugin");

        object plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        plugin.GetType().GetMethod("Run").Invoke(plugin, null);
    }
}
```

And this is the plugin (residing in an external assembly)

```
public class FooPlugin
{
    public void Run()
    {
        File.ReadAllText("C:\\Passwords.txt");
    }
}
```

I am strong naming the assembly containing `PluginHost` and therefore I expect to be able to read my passwords file from `PluginHost` and not from `FooPlugin` but the code throws a `SecurityException` when reading the file (in `PluginHost`).

My understanding from the [MSDN documentation on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766.aspx) was that the fourth parameter containing StrongName-instances will give those assemblies full trust in the application domain.

From the documentation:

> "An array of strong names representing assemblies to be considered
>   fully trusted in the new application domain."

**Since I just proved myself wrong - how am I supposed to get this to work?** Why am I not in full trust even though I've passed my `StrongName` to `AppDomain.Create`?

Comment: What does the `SecurityException` say?

Comment: It says that it could not demand a FileIOPermission for the Password.txt file, but I was expecting that exception in my plugin. Not in the PluginHost which is in a strongly named assembly.

Comment: After playing around with it, I've found out that in PluginHost you can assert an unrestricted permission set before the fileio call: `new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert()`

Comment: Hmm, very odd. I can't see why this shouldn't work. I suspect it may be something to do with loading the same assembly into two different appdomains, but I'm not sure. Try separating PluginHost into a different assembly.